# Gimp tool options tab shows only GEGL editing

Tags: gimp, tools, drawing-tablet

I'm relatively new to GIMP and now having the following problem. As of today, my tool options tab is only showing GEGL-editing. Out of everthing I've tried so far (including reinstalling GIMP) nothing seems to help. I'd really like my old tab (with opacity, size etc) back! Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: ***Welcome*** to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As currently framed, your question seems off-topic because it's essentially a tech support question, as it would require access to an individual file or machine. You might be able to [edit] your question to better fit our guidelines - *please* first read our [help/on-topic] page on what topics are appropriate here - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the software won't fix this. What you're describing is normal behaviour. There's nothing wrong.

After you've used a GEGL filter* and applied it, and before you continue editing, choose another Tool in the toolbox, such as the Paint Brush or the Move Tool, etc, and the tool options will revert to normal for the selected tool.

*Note: GEGL filters and operations appear in GIMP's menus with a large letter G icon before them.